# Load Testing in Struts2 Application - JMeter

Tags: jmeter, struts2

I am trying to do a load test using JMeter for the first Time.

My approach is to test each page one by one.

1. The main page is like http://localhost:8180/myapp/login.do?actionType=login(I hardcoded the credentials)
   I am able to reach this page without any problem.

   - I created a `HTTP request` component and able to see the response without any issue.
2. In the main page there is a button which populates the report, in the browser , the `url` is like 
   `http://localhost:8180/myapp/mainmenu.do`

   - But when i create a `HTTP request` it is reaching but shows the security error page in the 'Response 
     Data' as **Due to security reasons, we still recommend you to close this window.**

can someone guide me how to test the other pages without these security errors. This is a `struts2` Web application.

Comment: If it's struts2 web application then why it has a non standard url extension? AFAIK the extension `do` is a standard extension of Struts1 web applications. There is impossible to reproduce the error without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Misunderstanding a web application logic lacks to improve the quality of the qiestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding `HTTP Cookie Manger` and 
set `Cookie Policy` as `Standard`

[image]

click `HTTP Cookie Manager`

[image]

and click `save` icon on the top.

Source 
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_cookie_support

Thanks @Dimitri T and @Roman C for their valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what technology is being used under the hood of the web application you're testing you should stick to one simple rule:

**Well-behaved JMeter test must send exactly the same requests as real browser**

It includes:

- Same number/sequence/nature of the [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)
- Same [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (including [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies))

any dynamic values need to be properly [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)

Once JMeter will send the same requests as real browser does it should receive the same responses. So just use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the requests originating from browser and JMeter and amend JMeter's configuration until the requests start looking exactly the same. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Dimitri, the page I am having difficulty is `http://localhost:9080/myApp/mainmenu.do?actionType=displayDailyReport&moduleID=MONITORING&userName=user1` even in browser , if i directly try to access - It gives the same error which i get in JMeter, but in chrome browser if I access the mentioned link AFTER the login page  which is `http://localhost:9080/myApp/login.do?actionType=login` I am able to see the page in the browser. is this something due to Session or something ? can you please guide me how to resolve this issue in JMeter